# SQL Injection function of ' -- +'

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection

i set up an example server to learn more about SQL injections. 
I've found an instruction on http://sechow.com/bricks/docs/content-page-3.html
which contains the following example:

```
POST Data: username=tom' order by 1 -- +&submit=Submit
SQL Query: SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='harry' ORDER BY 1 -- +' 
The page displays the content without any issues and there are no error messages.
```

What is the function of ' -- + ' in the end of the query?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Iirc it's a start of a comment (-- specifically) so the rest of the query would be ignored.

Comment: Doesn't look like the POST data and SQL query have something to do with each other...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is comment the rest of the code. The inject part is the `ORDER BY 1`

Imagine your code is

```
WHERE login = 'tom' and password 'i dont know'
```

that will be change to

```
WHERE login = 'harry' ORDER BY 1 -- +and password 'i dont know'
```

EDIT

I just read the example. the `+ '` is to close the string

See how after the 2 the result have a `'` ?

```
POST Data: username=tom' and 1='2&submit=Submit
SQL Query: SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='harry' AND 1='2'
```

You other version will be

```
POST Data: username=tom' order by 1 -- +&submit=Submit
SQL Query: SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='harry' ORDER BY 1 -- +' 

SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE name='harry' 
ORDER BY 1 -- + ''
```

Comment: the sql injection does not work without -- +, I understand that oder by is the injection part, but why do i need to comment out the rest?

Comment: Are you sure? what error you got without it? You should be able to put `/` or `{` after `--` shouldnt matter

Comment: Well I disabled errors. I get the expected result with a -- +, the other versions like -- {  or -- / give me a blank page.

Comment: It might be that the + is there to make sure there is at least one recognised character inside the comment in case, like in OPs original example, the comment gets added at the end of the query. Can't be sure though.

Comment: @JonStirling I add some more information, but is weird you need add `+ '` to close the single quote, and the `--` coment doesnt ignore it.

Comment: In a non related issue, This answer make me reach 8000 points. Thanks  :)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I think the `'` is just a typo in this case. I believe the main thing it's adding is forcing there to be a space between the comment start and comment content. The plus I think is potentially there to prevent errors popping up from people trimming empty space from inputs causing the issue of there being no space between the start and content. I am just making (hopefully educated) guesses though :)